# Complex SQL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I form the following query using active record?

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM `course_enrollments` ce JOIN courses c ON ce.course_id = c.id 
WHERE ce.created_at
BETWEEN '2000-01-01' and '2012-01-01' [AND ANOTHER POSSIBLE CONDITION]
GROUP BY c.id
```

I want to be able to do something like: (I know the below is not correct, but I just want to show a general example)

```
courses = Course.joins(:course_enrollments).where('course_enrollments.created_at' => params[:start_date]..params[:end_date]).group('courses.id')

if some_condition
  courses = courses.where(:some_field => 1)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should get you on the way

```
Course.joins(:course_enrolements).
where("course_enrolements.created_at between '2000-01-01' and '2012-01-01'").
group("courses.id").
where(MORE CONDITIONS)
```

use `.to_sql` to analyze output

Comment: Should the where be: where("course_enrollments.created_at between ? and ?", params[:start_date], params[:end_date])

Comment: if they are variable, yes - otherwise, no. I don't use bind variables unless they are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Railscast](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3). There are quite a number of ways to do the same elegantly esp. to address your [AND ANOTHER POSSIBLE CONDITION] concern. Also take a look at [Squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) gem if its not suggested in the Railscast.